# ninja: fatal: chdir to '/out/Release' - No such file or directory

Tags: ninja

i get source code (chrome) by

```
$ glient sync
```

ran all the command request :

```
     - gclient config ......
  - GYP_GENERATORS ...
  - build/intall-build-desp.......
  - GYP_DEFINES....
  - etc...
```

but when i try to build chromedriver like this :

```
lolo@ssa-workstation:~/work$ ninja -C /out/Release chromedriver
```

i get always this message

```
ninja: Entering directory `/out/Release'
ninja: fatal: chdir to '/out/Release' - No such file or directory`
```

please any help ?

Comment: +1 I have exactly the same problem. However I have no idea how to use gclient config (and so on) either... The documentation is simply horrible.

Comment: You have to be in the `src` directory.

Answer (score 3):

Just found what worked for me (Mac OS X Catalina 10.15.2) - [source](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/0e94f26e8/docs/ios_build_instructions.md#with-gn)

*(Note: Probably you'll have to replace `ios` or `iphonesimulator` with `chromedriver` as I was building chromium for iOS)*

You have to enter `src` folder (after you used fetch - `fetch ios` in my case) and use `gn args out/Debug-iphonesimulator` (or replace `out/Debug-iphonesimulator` with your chosen `out/` directory) to open up an editor (`vi` editor in my case) to set the following `gn` variables and regenerate:

```
# Set to true if you have a valid code signing key.
ios_enable_code_signing = false
target_os = "ios"
# Set to "x86", "x64", "arm", "armv7", "arm64". "x86" and "x64" will create a
# build to run on the iOS simulator (and set use_ios_simulator = true), all
# others are for an iOS device.
target_cpu = "x64"
# Release vs debug build.
is_debug = true
```

After that you would be able to run your command without problems (but be sure that `depot_tools` are in your `$PATH`)

I run `autoninja -C out/Debug-iphonesimulator gn_all` and it worked like a charm :)

For reference I used official documentation from [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/0e94f26e8/docs/ios_build_instructions.md#with-gn) and [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/ios/build_instructions.md#Setting-up-the-build)

There is another option to use `GYP` instead of `gn` on same documentation page (I didn't try by myself, but it could help someone anyway):

In the directory where you are going to check out the code, create a `chromium.gyp_env` to set the build to use iOS targets:

```
cat > chromium.gyp_env <<EOF
{
  "GYP_DEFINES": "OS=ios",
  "GYP_GENERATORS": "ninja,xcode-ninja",
}
EOF
```

If you aren't set up to sign iOS build products via a developer account, you should instead use:

```
cat > chromium.gyp_env <<EOF
{
  "GYP_DEFINES": "OS=ios chromium_ios_signing=0",
  "GYP_GENERATORS": "ninja,xcode-ninja",
}
EOF
```

Hope this could save someone a lot of time looking for answer :)